# MySQL выборка записей созданных более часа назад

Tags: mysql, datetime, timestamp

Есть табличка table с полем date типа datetime, у которого значение по умолчанию установлено CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. Соответственно при создании записей в такой табличке, в поле date лежат даты создания. Мне нужно выбрать все записи созданные более часа назад, как мне лучше это сделать?

Пробовал так:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date <= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR);
```

Но получается какая-то ерунда...

**UPD.**

Я понял в чем дело, но не знаю как пофиксить. Запрос вида

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR;
```

или

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date <= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR);
```

действительно возвращает правильный результат, но у меня запрос сложнее (вот уж не думал, что это может оказаться граблями). В table есть еще одно поле - status типа tinyint(1) и значением по умолчанию 0. И когда мой запрос выглядит так:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE status = 0 AND date <= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR);
```

или так

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE status <> 1 AND date <= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR);
```

то выборка получается неправильная. Причем если сделать отдельно:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE status = 0;
```

то все нужные записи там будут.

Как бы это пофиксить?

Comment: А какая именно ерунда получается ? запрос то рабочий ...

Comment: Выдаются не все записи старше часа, а записи в промежутке в час за час от текущего времени.

Comment: Попробовал вот так SELECT * FROM table WHERE date <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR; Вроде выдает то, что я хочу. Правильное ли это решение?

Comment: Не может этого быть. если запрос в точности такой как приведенный - ищите ошибку либо в данных (записей с искомыми датами физически нет в БД) либо в чем то, что ограничивает получение записей (например утилиты работы с MySQL, на подобии sql-workbench любят добавлять к запросу limit 1000)

Comment: Да, второй запрос то же правильный. Они идентичны

Comment: Отписал в шапку результаты, но не знаю как починить...

Comment: Только вы не написали что же вы хотите получить. `status=0 and date <= ...` сделает ровно то, что ожидается оставит только записи со статусом 0 старше 1 часа

Comment: Так в том то и дело, что не возвращает. Мне действительно нужны все записи, созданные более часа назад со статусом 0. Но мне выдаются не все из этих записей, а только несколько. Но я своими глазами вижу, что их в базе больше.

Comment: Но этого не может быть ... внимательнее присмотритесь к записям которые не выдаются. что то в них не так, либо не 0 либо дата все таки не на час отстает, а может меньше

Comment: Я все проверил. Даты правильные, в статусах действительно 0. Даже время в ОС правильное... Мистика одним словом.

Comment: На удачу попробовал сделать в абсолютных числах: SELECT * FROM table WHERE status = 0 AND date <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() - 3600; И о чудо! Оно заработало. По крайней мере показывает результаты похожие на правду.

Comment: Предполагаю, что суть проблемы - в том, что поле `table.date` имеет тип TIMESTAMP, а на сервере и клиенте имеет место натуральный бардак с зонами времени. Рекомендация в таком случае - изменить тип данных на DATETIME.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE status = 0 AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 3600;
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать SQL-запрос с условием `WHERE` и функцией `DATE_SUB`.

```
SELECT * FROM [Your table]
WHERE date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR);
```

Собственно, ничего сложного. Мы получаем все записи и все столбцы `*`, которые были созданы час назад.

Чтобы добавить другие фильтры для `WHERE` мы можем использовать оператор `AND`, пример запроса с записями, которые были созданы час назад и которые имеют `status` = `1`:

```
SELECT * FROM [Your table]
WHERE date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
AND status = 0;
```